# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token > when loading Phonegap app on Android phone

Tags: javascript, webpack, phonegap

--- UPDATE ---

Error disappeared when setting NODE_ENV=production before my webpack build-step. I still don't know what the underlying cause for this issue was.

--- END UPDATE ---

I have made a Phonegap app using Webpack. The app works fine on iOS and other Android devices, but it crashes on a Huawei Honor H60-L04 with Android 4.4.2. It crashes on load, showing this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >

By adding/removing all scripts loaded in index.html one by one, I have isolated the problem to exist in the dist/build.js file. That is the resulting js file from Webpack build, with all the app logic inside. Is there some webpack config mistake causing this issue? And why is only this device getting the error?

If relevant, I am using Vue.js and Framework7 to develop the app, and Phonegap Build to build it.

--- UPDATE --- :

When remote debugging the console says the error is at line 85 in index.html, but the index.html is not that long. Guessing that line number reports that way because dynamic things are added to the html-file when trying to load script.

My entire .babelrc file:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-shorthand-properties"]
}
```

My entire Webpack config file:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          sass: "vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass?indentedSyntax"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue',
      'Framework7Vue': path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/framework7-vue/dist/framework7-vue.min.js')
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

--- END UPDATE ---

Comment: Can you please give us some code?

Comment: Since this is such an extremely isolated incident, this is something that will be nearly impossible to troubleshoot in a stack overflow question regardless of how much data you provide.  Posting your entire webpack config though would be a great start, its possible you have misconfigured something in webpack, although its highly unlikely.  Something on the phone may be reacting strangely to some of webpack's pollyfills as well, you might be able to substitute different pollyfills but that could break other devices potentially.

Comment: Also if the phone gives a line# the error occurs on, or what file if you have sourcemaps that could be helpful.   Its possible you forgot a self closing tag or something and that phone is reacting strangely to the missing close tag.  Use html hint and go through all your html files to see if your missing close tags.

Comment: @thomasmeadows Thanks for answering. Updated question with Webpack config-file.